# How to POST new product in shopify store via api from a private app?

Tags: api, shopify

i'm using shopify_app gem and i was able to read to my shop. but then i can't write to it. i have set up the read/write credentials while installing my app so i'm sure the problem's not there. here's what i did to POST a new product in my shop:

```
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
product.title= "Nike Bag"
product.price_range = "27.00"
product.save
```

but it doesn't save.
Thank you so much. I need this badly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this problem has already been solved in the [shopify api google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shopify-api/3RLKP9IYZ7w), but just posting it here just in case somebody else finds it useful.

The product above can't be saved because not all required fields are specified. Check the sample in the [shopify api docs](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#create) for a list of required fields. Also check product.errors if save fails, which should give an idea of why it failed.

This should work:

```
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
product.product_type = "Snowboard"
product.title = "Burton Custom Freestlye 151"
product.body_html  = "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>"
product.vendor = "Burton"
product.variants = [ShopifyAPI::Variant.new(:price =>10)]
product.save
```